# Background color of kate's search/replace input fields

Tags: gnome, themes, kde, kate

I'm using kate on my ubuntu 13.04 unity without any problems. Even the dark mediterranean-themes (http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=156782) look great inside kate.

As you may see in the screenshots, this is a theme with dark background and bright foreground (some greyish-white). If I now start search/replace inside kate, the input text field has a dark background and bright foreground as expected from the theme. Depending on the matches, kate changes the background on-the-fly to some light green or light red, without altering the foreground color. This makes reading extremely difficult.

Is there a way to adjust the foreground color or disable this behavior? I already searched Fonts & Colors inside the configuration, but this menu entry seems to be restricted to the editor only. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is the Gnome Color Chooser app that allows you to customize the desktop. Install by issuing the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser
```

If will then show up in the `System Tools | Preferences` menu. Can also type `gnome-color-chooser` from terminal.

In the "Global Colors" tab there is a "Entry Field" section. I'd experiment by adjusting those colors to see if you get a better result.

Answer (score 0):

In Mint 18 Cinnamon (Gnome)(Ubuntu based):
Menu >> Preferences >> KDE System Settings >> Color >> Zion(reversed)

So you need to install KDE config apps for Ubuntu if they are not installed. "KDE System Settings" in Mint == "systemsettings5" command.

And then in Kate:
Settings >> Configure Kate >> Fonts and Colors >> Default Schema for Kate 
Set to "KDE"

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This site is devoted to Ubuntu. Answers regarding Mint are welcome at our sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com/